# How to search for a string in a text file and perform a specific action based on the result

Tags: bash

I have very little experience with Bash but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have two different text files with a bunch of server names in them. Before installing any windows updates and rebooting them, I need to disable all the nagios host/service alerts.

```
host=/Users/bob/WSUS/wsus_test.txt
password="my_password"

while read -r host
do
  curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" "https://nagios.fqdn.here/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k
done < wsus_test.txt >> /Users/bob/WSUS/diable_test.log 2>&1
```

This is a reduced form of my current code which works as intended, however, we have servers in a bunch of regions. Each server name is prepended with a 3 letter code based on region (ie, LAX, NYC, etc). Secondly, we have a nagios server in each region so I need the code above to be connecting to the correct regional nagios server based on the server name being passed in.

I tried adding 4 test servers into a text file and just adding a line like this:

```
    if grep lax1 /Users/bob/WSUS/wsus_text.txt; then
      <same command as above but with the regional nagios server name>
    fi
```

This doesn't work as intended and nothing is actually disabled/enabled via API calls. Again, I've done very little with Bash so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste a few sample lines from wsus_text.txt?

Comment: oh it's just FQDNs so its just something like lax1-fs01.company.priv, lax1-ts01.company.priv, nyc1-dc01.company.priv, etc. Separate FQDN on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the region from host name and use it in the Nagios URL, like this:

```
while read -r host; do
  region=$(cut -f1 -d- <<< "$host")
  curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" "https://nagios-$region.fqdn.here/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k
done < wsus_test.txt >> /Users/bob/WSUS/diable_test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: ahhh makes sense. Looks like this should work. I'll test it out and mark it as the answer when I confirm it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the logs, this appears to work, but when I run it against multiple server's some work and some don't. In my log file I see a message that says "* Connection #0 to host <server_name> left intact" but I never see a connection closed message. I originally thought this may be the problem when jumping from one server to the next, but I did a test wth hostnames that reside on the same nagios server and I get the same behavior. Any ideas?