# While loop to execute nagios commands not working properly

Tags: bash, while-loop, nagios

I wrote a small bash script in this post: [How to search for a string in a text file and perform a specific action based on the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403638/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-a-text-file-and-perform-a-specific-action-based-on)

I noticed that when I ran the script and check the logs, everything appears to be working but when I look at the Nagios UI, almost half of the servers listed in my text file did not get their notifications disabled. A revised version of the script is below:

```
host=/Users/bob/wsus.txt

password="P@assw0rd123"

while read -r host; do
    region=$(echo "$host" | cut -f1 -d-)

    if [[ $region == *sea1* ]]
        then
            echo "Disabling host notifications for: $host"
            curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" https://nagios.$region.blah.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k 2>&1
        else
            echo "Disabling host notifications for: $host"
            curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" https://nagios.$region.blah02.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k 2>&1
    fi
done < wsus.txt >> /Users/bob/disable.log 2>&1
```

If i run the command against the servers having the issue manually, it does get disabled in the Nagios UI, so I'm a bit confused. FYI, I'm not well versed in Bash either so this was my attempt at trying to automate this process a bit.

Comment: Are you able to determine from your log if the problem is caused by the "while" loop not reading lines for the missing servers, or if it is because the command is called but fails?

Comment: Rename the host var to `hostsfile=/Users/bob/wsus.txt`, make sure that file exists, then change the done line to `done < $hostsfile >> /Users/bob/disable.log 2>&1`. That should do it.

Comment: @NagiosSupport That worked, thanks! I also noticed that some of the "failing" servers before had the wrong FQDN in my text file...

Answer (score 0):

1 - There is a missing double-quote before the first https occurence:

You have:

```
curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" https://nagios.$region.blah.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k 2>&1
```

Should be:

```
curl -vs -o /dev/null -d "cmd_mod=2&cmd_typ=25&host=$host&btnSubmit=Commit" "https://nagios.$region.blah.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi" -u "bob:$password" -k 2>&1
```

2 - Your first variable `host` is never used (overwritten inside the while loop).
I'm guessing what you were trying to do was something like:

```
hosts_file="/Users/bob/wsus.txt"
log_file="/Users/bob/disable.log"

# ...

while read -r host; do
    # Do stuff with $host
done < $hosts_file >> $log_file 2>&1
```

3 - This looks suspicious to me:

```
if [[ $region == *sea1* ]]
```

Note: I haven't tested it yet, so this is my general feeling about this, might be wrong.

The `$region` isn't double-quoted, so make sure there could be no spaces / funny stuff happening there (but this should not be a problem inside a double-bracket test `[[`).

The `*sea*` looks like it would be expanded to match your current directory files matching this globbing. If you want to test this as a regular expression, you should use `~=` operator or (my favorite for some reason) `grep` command:

```
if grep -q ".*sea.*" <<< "$region"; then
    # Your code if match
else
    # Your code if no match
fi
```

- The `-q` keeps `grep` **q**uiet
- There is no need for test like `[` or `[[` because the return code of `grep` is already 0 if any match
- The `<<<` simply redirects the right strings as the standard input of the left command (avoid useless piping like `echo "$region" | grep -q ".*sea.*"`).

If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide a sample of your input file `hosts_file` as well as some output logs.

You could also try to see what's really going on under the hood by enclosing your script with `set -x` and `set +x` to activate debug/trace mode.

Comment: thanks, but after I made the changes @NagiosSupport recommended, i can confirm via the Nagios web UI that all the problematic hosts not are responding correctly and the notifications are disabled.